# How to read one specific column from table() in R

Tags: r

From a 100000+ rows table I generated this small table with `table()` in R:

```
> TableName <- table(ProductID = test$ProductID,format(test$Dates, "%y%m%d"))
> TableName 

ProductID 161024 161025 161026 161027 161028 161029 161030
      1      1      2      4      1      2      3      5
      2      4      4      7      3      8      1      8
      3      1      1      1      0      0      0      0
      6      1      1      1      0      0      0      0
      8      3      9      8      6      1      7      3
```

In the normal time, I can read one specific column with `TableName$ColumnName` but it doesn't work with the table generated from `table()` unless I write this table to a .csv file.

Is there any way that I can read one specific column without write the table to a .csv file and read the same .csv file back to R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `matrix`, `table`, the `$` will not work, so, we need to use `[`

```
TableName[, '161024']
```

Comment: How to read the first column '"ProductID"'? '[,"ProductID"]' shows me an error message and '[,1]' can only read the first date column.

Comment: @Y.Z.  You can either use `"ProductID"` or its index i.e `[,1]` to select that column.  Based on a reproducible example `tbl <- table(sample(1:3, 24, replace=TRUE), sample(1:7, 24, replace=TRUE)); tbl[,1]` I couldn't find any errors

Comment: @Y.Z.  I think the `ProductID"` is the name of the `dimnames`, so it is not a column.

Comment: I think the table thinks my first column is "161024" instead of "ProductID". [,1] only shows me the "161024" column.

Comment: @Y.Z.  There is no column.  `tbl <- table(col1=sample(1:3, 24, replace=TRUE), col2=sample(1:7, 24, replace=TRUE))`  To check it, `dimnames(tbl)` and `names(dimnames(tbl))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127644/discussion-between-y-z-and-akrun).